Getting xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax from grid in QGIS
I need to obtain the xmin, xmax, ymin, and ymax coordinates of grid cells, to precisely export each grid cell of a raster map to MBtiles. This grid was created and modified using GlobalMapper software.
The coordinates I obtain by right-clicking and selecting "Copy Coordinates" on a cell are not suitable for file extraction. I would like, if it's possible, to get the xmin, xmax, ymin and ymax here, so I can easily do it:

Here are the details I have in the attribute table. Maybe I have to create new columns and generate them myself?


You can also use a Python script in the Python Console (Ctrl+Alt+P) -> Show Editor).
from qgis.core import QgsProject

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('grid')[0]

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    extent = feature.geometry().boundingBox()
    extentStr = "{},{},{},{} [{}]".format(extent.xMinimum(), extent.xMaximum(), extent.yMinimum(), extent.yMaximum(), layer.crs().authid())
    print (extentStr)

Replace "grid" with the name of your layer.
Sample output:
150.2552396970781, 150.25608732222736, -33.6295835608667, -33.62861757504505 [EPSG:4326]
150.2814562992131, 150.2819553870153, -33.62194763971622, -33.62160264285498 [EPSG:4326]
150.27930396723343, 150.2796963567394, -33.620955524378104, -33.62057437566147 [EPSG:4326]
150.27989230894724, 150.28078197525184, -33.62002862179687, -33.61944064713204 [EPSG:4326]


You can create four new columns.
Field calculator expression with x_min, y_min, x_max, and y_max functions (see the Geometry Functions for more details):

Returns the minimum y coordinate of a geometry. Calculations are in
the spatial reference system of this geometry.



Thank you so much! You've probably saved my day, and possibly months of work!
Sorry to bother you with another question, do you think it's possible to make my own CRS (or maybe one already exists) to get this information by right clicking on the cells > copy coordinates?
I've tried searching the internet, stackexchange and ask chatgpt but can't find the solution

Nice. I dont understand you fully. You've seen this option right?

Sorry, it's a bit confusing! x) It's this very menu I was talking about, and I can't figure out how to create my own CRS using the coordinates xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax (or maybe they already exist?)

Salut. Not sure what you are asking for (do you want xmin/ymin to be reported as 0/0 ?). In any case you should ask another question as it seems different from the initial question here.

Another option is to use the "Extract Layer Extent" tool in QGIS.
It accepts either a vector or raster as input. It will output a polygon of the area extent, and in the attribute table of this layer, there will be several fields including minx, miny, maxx, and maxy.
Make sure your layer is in the appropriate CRS for your needs (i.e., if you want Northings and Eastings, make sure it's projected, otherwise if you want lat/lon make sure it's in a geographic CRS).

Thank you very much! I'm going to try this tomorrow. It's possible, given the number of parameters and my current level on QGIS, that I'll need your help if you don't mind! :)

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with my map source... I get this error message :
ERROR 4: `http-header:referer=&tilePixelRatio=1&type=xyz&url=https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/%7Bz%7D/%7By%7D/%7Bx%7D&zmax=20&zmin=0' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.
I've also tried with another source (local source) and it gives me the same error :/

Ah, I did not realize you were using a service layer. I should have specified that this approach won't work for service layers. My apologies.

No problem! Thanks anyway for taking the time to give me a solution :)
